# MVC site not loading from IIS .Server is new one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server, iis-7

I have a DEV **server** which is pretty **new** and i hosted MVC application.But while browsing it shows "Requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid".When i remove the corresponding error tag from web.config another error "IIS directory listing is not enabled for the website or application" and i enabled the directory listing.Still the site is not loading .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search i found that ,since the server is "NEW" we need to set some settings in **Windows features** and it is one time config.
We have to turn on or check the features related to

1. .Net Framework
2. WCF Services
3. Asp.net 4.5

Now the MVC site is up and running .

To turn Windows features on or off, follow these steps in this [site](http://www.dell.com/support/article/in/en/indhs1/sln288491/how-to-turn-windows-features-on-or-off-in-windows-7-?lang=en):